# The difference between authority and scheme in an Android URI

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, authority

What is the difference between URI authority and URI scheme in Android?
I always use scheme in URI to indicate database table as follow:

```
content://scheme
```

I using custom search suggestion in my application, I read document about search custom suggestion in which authority used instead of scheme to reference database as follow:

```
content://your.authority/opthional.suggest.path/SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY
```

What is `my.authority` above? What is the difference between this and scheme?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> i always use scheme in uri to indicate database table as follow `content://scheme`

`scheme` is not the scheme. `content` is the scheme, following [the rules for URI values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme). What you have as `scheme` is what in an Android `content://` `Uri` is referred to as the authority.

> what is my.authoruty above ?

It is the authority. It needs to be in `android:authorities` attribute for your `<provider>` in your manifest, and it is used by Android to find the one true `ContentProvider` for any `Uri`.

> what is the difference between this and scheme ?

They are the same, because you are misusing the term "scheme".

Comment: now i understand authority and uri ,but  to access database i use contentresolver.query() ,query first argument is uri  this.uri writen as follow (e.g.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) it seems like directories seperated by period. uri should be content://provider/<path> path is optional, what is the difference between uri like this and uri defined in manifest it way you mentioned above?

Comment: @MohabMohamed: "uri writen as follow (e.g.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) it seems like directories seperated by period" -- no. [`EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` is a `Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) that is a Java `static` data member of the `MediaStore.Audio.Media` Java class.